# How to use condition in HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am loading an image in a new window when user click a button in Angular.
The popup which I opened contains HTML.

Angular HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="openDocument(doc)"> View </button>
```

TS:

```
openDocument(doc) {
    doc.uploadedDocUrl = "https://beta.lottoweaver.com/WeaverDoc/commonContent/www.nationallottery.co.za/playerDocument/408441_ID_PROOF_null_1616082462069.pdf"

    let str = `<embed src=${doc.uploadedDocUrl} width='100%' height="100%">`;
    
    this.OpenWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=900, height=600, left=200, top=100');
    this.OpenWindow.document.write(`<body onload="checkIfPdf(${doc.uploadedDocUrl})">${str}</body>
    <script>
    function checkIfPdf(doc) {
      if(doc.endsWith(".pdf")) {
        console.log("is pdf")
      } else {
        console.log("is not pdf")
     }
    }
    </script>
    `);
    this.OpenWindow.document.close();
  }
```

I want keep width and height attributes as `100%` if the doc file ends with ".pdf"
else I want to keep width and height attributes as `auto`.

How to write this condition?

Working stackblitz= https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ns536z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define another function in ts file call it to assign value of `let str = this.pdfchecker(url)`

Where pdfchecker will look something like this:

```
pdfchecker(url){
    
const last = url.split('.');
if(last[last.length -1] == 'pdf'){
    let str = //value of str
    return str
}else{
    let str = //other value of str
    return str
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know angular but. your code is like

```
 <script>
   function checkIfPdf(doc) {
   if(doc.endsWith(".pdf")) {
   console.log("is pdf")
   } else {
   console.log("is not pdf")
   }
   }
   </script>
  `);
   this.OpenWindow.document.close();
you may check with 

   <script>
  function checkIfPdf(doc) {
   if(doc.endsWith(".pdf")) {
   console.log("is pdf")
   } else {
   console.log("is not pdf")
   }
   }
  `);
   this.OpenWindow.document.close();
  </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to use nested if

It may go like this

```
if (condition a) 
{
    do action 1
} else 
{
   if (condition b) 
   {
     do action 2
   } 
   else 
   {
     ... etc.
   }
}
```

Comment: How to use this on HTML to decide width and height attributes of `embed`?

Comment: But you have decided the height and width in your code itself, right?

Comment: no, right now, it is `width='100%' height="100%"` but I want something like `checkIfPdf() ? width='100%' height="100%" : width="auto" height="auto"`